# Como manter os filtros da consulta enviados via $_POST?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$page = ((isset($_GET['pagina']) && intval($_GET['pagina']) > 1)? intval($_GET['pagina']) : 1) - 1;
$limite = 12;
$atual = $page * $limite;
$limit = " LIMIT {$atual}, {$limite}";

// Registros limitados
$query    = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM imovel ".trim($where, ' AND ').$limit); 
$total    = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM imovel ".trim($where, ' AND '));
$total2   = $total->rowCount();
$qtdpage  = ceil($total2/$limite); // Quantidade de páginas

for ($i = 1; $i < $qtdpage; $i++){
     echo '<li><a href="busca?pagina='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></li>';
}
```

Com este código estou recuperando os registros da minha consulta e recuperando o total de registros dessa consulta.

As variáveis do filtro estão sendo enviadas via `POST` e quando eu troco de página tipo da **1** para  a **2**, o filtro é perdido, ou seja, ele entende que não foi passado parâmetros e então aplica a busca padrão.

Como, ao clicar na página `2`, `3`, `4` manter os parâmetros da busca atual?

> Isso é o que acontece quando passo para a página 2 ou outra qualquer.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assim como o @Bacco comentou, que pode ter vários filtros em abas diferêntes, ou seja, usando a mesma sessão, pode-se usar o filtro via *GET*, que é bem plausível.

```
<?php
   $filtro = '';
   if (isset($_REQUEST['imovel'])){ // REQUEST busca os dados tanto de POST como de GET
     $imovel = $_REQUEST['imovel']; // Trate o SQL Injection
     $where = " imovel = {$imovel} AND "
     $filtro .= '&imovel='.urlencode($imovel);
   }

     $page = ((isset($_GET['pagina']) && intval($_GET['pagina']) > 1)? intval($_GET['pagina']) : 1) - 1;
     $limite = 12;
     $atual = $page * $limite;
     $limit = " LIMIT {$atual}, {$limite}";



     // Registros limitados
     $query    = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM imovel ".trim($where, ' AND ').$limit); 
     $total    = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM imovel ".trim($where, ' AND '));
     $total2   = $total->rowCount();
     $qtdpage  = ceil($total2/$limite); // Quantidade de páginas

     for ($i = 1; $i < $qtdpage; $i++){
          echo '<li><a href="busca?pagina='.$i.$filtro.'">'.$i.'</a></li>';
     }
```

---

Ou armazene os dados da consulta em sessões:

```
<?php
   session_start();
   if (isset($_POST['imovel'])){
     $_SESSION['filtro'] = Array();
     // Não se esquça de fazer tratamento para SQL Injection
     $_SESSION['filtro']['imovel'] = $_POST['imovel']; 
   }

     $page = ((isset($_GET['pagina']) && intval($_GET['pagina']) > 1)? intval($_GET['pagina']) : 1) - 1;
     $limite = 12;
     $atual = $page * $limite;
     $limit = " LIMIT {$atual}, {$limite}";

     if (isset($_SESSION['filtro']['imovel'])){
        $where = " imovel = {$_SESSION['filtro']['imovel']} AND "
     }

     // Registros limitados
     $query    = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM imovel ".trim($where, ' AND ').$limit); 
     $total    = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM imovel ".trim($where, ' AND '));
     $total2   = $total->rowCount();
     $qtdpage  = ceil($total2/$limite); // Quantidade de páginas

     for ($i = 1; $i < $qtdpage; $i++){
          echo '<li><a href="busca?pagina='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></li>';
     }
```

Answer (score 3):

Se eu percebi bem perdes os valores da consulta e para manteres os valores visto que passas por `POST` basta carregares os mesmos no `input` da consulta, fica o exemplo:

```
echo "<input name='consulta'";
if($consulta = filter_input(INPUT_POST , 'consulta'))
    echo "value='$consulta'"; 
echo ">";
```

Comment: A minha paginação não faz uma consulta, só tenta mudar para a página `2` visto que eu já carreguei tudo que eu precisava na primeira consulta.

Comment: Não estou a entender o teu problema então...